# browse function not giving output in Rshiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I am building on shiny App. Following code is giving perfect output. I feel some issue in placement of commoa or ) but I am not able to figure out, this issue was possible because of same output/id but I have correct that as well still not able to solve the issue

````
  dashboardHeader(title = "Inventory Management" , titleWidth = 800)
  ,
  dashboardSidebar(
    #sliderInput("bins", "Number of inputs", 1,100,50),
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("data", tabName = "Page1" , icon=icon("tachometer"))
      ,menuItem("Summary", tabName = "Page2" , icon=icon("tachometer"))
      #,menuItem("logic", tabName = "Page3" , icon=icon("tachometer"))
    )
  )
  ,dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      ### Data upload
      tabItem("Page1",
              fluidRow(
                ## Previos month's sales office data upload    
                column(3,fileInput("file1", "Previous Month close Sales office"))
                ## Previos month's DC data upload
                ,column(3,fileInput("file2", "Previous Month close DC"))
                ## Import Credit report upload
                ,column(3,fileInput("file3", "Import Credit Report"))
                ## Fusion Stock Outward Report - In upload
                ,column(3,fileInput("file4", "Fusion Stock Outward Report - In")))
            ## Display of data 
                      #Display of data from Previos month's sales office 
                     ,fluidRow(column(3,box(dataTableOutput("state_lst1")))
                                  # Display of data from Previos month's dc 
                                  ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set22")))
                                  # Display of data from Previos month's Import credit 
                                  ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set33")))
                                  # Display of data from Fusion stock report - in
                                  ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set44"))))
              ,br()
              ## Download of unique states
                        ## states from Prv month'ss Sales office
                        ,fluidRow(column(3,downloadButton("prv_mnt_so", "Download"))
                                  ## states from Prv month'ss DC
                                  ,column(3,downloadButton("prv_mnt_dc", "Download"))
                                  ## states from Import credit report
                                  ,column(3,downloadButton("imp_crdt_rpt", "Download"))
                                  ## states from Fusion stocl report
                                  ,column(3,downloadButton("Fs_stk_rpt_in", "Download")))
              ,br()
              ,br()
              ,br()
            
            #upload data continue.....
                ,fluidRow(
                        ## Hana Fusion Trade data upload    
                         column(3,fileInput("file5", "Hana Fusion Trade"))
                        ## Fusion Stock Outward Report - Out data upload    
                        ,column(3,fileInput("file6", "Fusion Stock Outward Report - Out"))
                        ## Current Month's close Sales office data upload    
                        ,column(3,fileInput("file7", "Current Month's close Sales office"))
                        ## Current Month's close DC data upload
                        ,column(3,fileInput("file8", "Current Month's close DC")))
            
            ## Display of data 
            #Display of states from Hana Fusion Trade data
            ,fluidRow(column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set55")))
                      # Display of states from Fusion Stock Outward Report - Out data upload  
                      ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set66")))
                      # Display of states from Current Month's close Sales office data
                      ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set77")))
                      # Display of states from Current Month's close dc data
                      ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set88"))))
                ,br()
            ## Download of unique states
            ## states from Hana Fusion Trade
            ,fluidRow(column(3,downloadButton("hn_fs_tr", "Download"))
                      ## states from Fusion Stock Outward Report - Out data upload  
                      ,column(3,downloadButton("Fs_stk_rpt_ot", "Download"))
                      ## states from Current Month's close Sales office data
                      ,column(3,downloadButton("crt_mnt_so", "Download"))
                      ## states from Current Month's close dc data
                      ,column(3,downloadButton("crt_mnt_dc", "Download")))
            #,tabItem(tabName = "Page3", p("This is page 3"))
    )
    ,tabItem("Page2"
             # , p("Analysis Outcome")
             ,fluidRow(
               box( title = "summary of Previous Month's Sales office", status = "primary", height = 
                                  "375",width = "6",solidHeader = T, 
                            column(3,DT::dataTableOutput("Prv_mnth_so_sm"),style = "height:300px; width:600px;  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"
                                   ))
               ,box( title = "summary of Previous Month's DC", status = "primary", height = 
                       "375",width = "6",solidHeader = T, 
                     column(3,DT::dataTableOutput("Prv_mnth_dc_sm"),style = "height:300px; width:600px;  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"
                     )))
             ))))```
but when I add another fluidRow i don't get anyoutcome after uploading file. though it doesn's show any error either
```ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Inventory Management" , titleWidth = 800)
  ,
  dashboardSidebar(
    #sliderInput("bins", "Number of inputs", 1,100,50),
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("data", tabName = "Page1" , icon=icon("tachometer"))
      ,menuItem("Summary", tabName = "Page2" , icon=icon("tachometer"))
      #,menuItem("logic", tabName = "Page3" , icon=icon("tachometer"))
    )
  )
  ,dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      ### Data upload
      tabItem("Page1",
              fluidRow(
                ## Previos month's sales office data upload    
                column(3,fileInput("file1", "Previous Month close Sales office"))
                ## Previos month's DC data upload
                ,column(3,fileInput("file2", "Previous Month close DC"))
                ## Import Credit report upload
                ,column(3,fileInput("file3", "Import Credit Report"))
                ## Fusion Stock Outward Report - In upload
                ,column(3,fileInput("file4", "Fusion Stock Outward Report - In")))
            ## Display of data 
                      #Display of data from Previos month's sales office 
                     ,fluidRow(column(3,box(dataTableOutput("state_lst1")))
                                  # Display of data from Previos month's dc 
                                  ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set22")))
                                  # Display of data from Previos month's Import credit 
                                  ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set33")))
                                  # Display of data from Fusion stock report - in
                                  ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set44"))))
              ,br()
              ## Download of unique states
                        ## states from Prv month'ss Sales office
                        ,fluidRow(column(3,downloadButton("prv_mnt_so", "Download"))
                                  ## states from Prv month'ss DC
                                  ,column(3,downloadButton("prv_mnt_dc", "Download"))
                                  ## states from Import credit report
                                  ,column(3,downloadButton("imp_crdt_rpt", "Download"))
                                  ## states from Fusion stocl report
                                  ,column(3,downloadButton("Fs_stk_rpt_in", "Download")))
              ,br()
              ,br()
              ,br()
            
            #upload data continue.....
                ,fluidRow(
                        ## Hana Fusion Trade data upload    
                         column(3,fileInput("file5", "Hana Fusion Trade"))
                        ## Fusion Stock Outward Report - Out data upload    
                        ,column(3,fileInput("file6", "Fusion Stock Outward Report - Out"))
                        ## Current Month's close Sales office data upload    
                        ,column(3,fileInput("file7", "Current Month's close Sales office"))
                        ## Current Month's close DC data upload
                        ,column(3,fileInput("file8", "Current Month's close DC")))
            
            ## Display of data 
            #Display of states from Hana Fusion Trade data
            ,fluidRow(column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set55")))
                      # Display of states from Fusion Stock Outward Report - Out data upload  
                      ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set66")))
                      # Display of states from Current Month's close Sales office data
                      ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set77")))
                      # Display of states from Current Month's close dc data
                      ,column(3,box(dataTableOutput("data_set88"))))
                ,br()
            ## Download of unique states
            ## states from Hana Fusion Trade
            ,fluidRow(column(3,downloadButton("hn_fs_tr", "Download"))
                      ## states from Fusion Stock Outward Report - Out data upload  
                      ,column(3,downloadButton("Fs_stk_rpt_ot", "Download"))
                      ## states from Current Month's close Sales office data
                      ,column(3,downloadButton("crt_mnt_so", "Download"))
                      ## states from Current Month's close dc data
                      ,column(3,downloadButton("crt_mnt_dc", "Download")))
            #,tabItem(tabName = "Page3", p("This is page 3"))
    )
    ,tabItem("Page2"
             # , p("Analysis Outcome")
             ,fluidRow(
               box( title = "summary of Previous Month's Sales office", status = "primary", height = 
                                  "375",width = "6",solidHeader = T, 
                            column(3,DT::dataTableOutput("Prv_mnth_so_sm"),style = "height:300px; width:600px;  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"
                                   ))
               ,box( title = "summary of Previous Month's DC", status = "primary", height = 
                       "375",width = "6",solidHeader = T, 
                     column(3,DT::dataTableOutput("Prv_mnth_dc_sm"),style = "height:300px; width:600px;  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"
                     )))
             ,fluidRow(
               box( title = "summary of imported credit report", status = "primary", height =
                       "375",width = "6",solidHeader = T,
                     column(3,DT::dataTableOutput("imp_crdt_rpt"),style = "height:300px; width:600px;  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"
                     ))
               ,box( title = "summary of Fs_stk_rpt_in", status = "primary", height =
                       "375",width = "6",solidHeader = T,
                     column(3,DT::dataTableOutput("Fs_stk_rpt_in"),style = "height:300px; width:600px;  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"
                     ))
               )
             ,fluidRow(
               box( title = "summary of Hana Fusion Trade", status = "primary", height =
                      "375",width = "6",solidHeader = T,
                    column(3,DT::dataTableOutput("Hana Fusion Trade"),style = "height:300px; width:600px;  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"
                    ))
               ,box( title = "summary of Fusion Stock Outward Report - Out", status = "primary", height =
                       "375",width = "6",solidHeader = T,
                     column(3,DT::dataTableOutput("Fusion Stock Outward Report - Out"),style = "height:300px; width:600px;  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"
                     ))
             )
             ,fluidRow(box( title = "summary of current Month's DC", status = "primary", height =
                               "375",width = "6",solidHeader = T,
                             column(3,DT::dataTableOutput("crt_mnt_so_sm"),style = "height:300px; width:600px;  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"
                             ))
                        ,box( title = "summary of Previous Month's DC", status = "primary", height =
                                "375",width = "6",solidHeader = T,
                              column(3,DT::dataTableOutput("crt_mnt_dc_sm"),style = "height:300px; width:600px;  overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;"
                              ))
                )
             
             ))))
````

There is **no change in server** between above two cases

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I was using same ids in second Fluidrow onwards, I corrected it and it is working fine